# How should my type habits change in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm getting started in swift by converting some of my old Obj-C libraries. It's honestly kind of painful, and I'm wondering if my habits are bad or something since everything I've read has talked about how easy it is to pick up swift. Specifically:

- No implicit type conversion clutters up code, and makes things like multiplying by a for loop counter less convenient. Is there a better way to deal with this?
- Array use is also kind of verbose. Are there any shorter ways to use Arrays as arguments, or to declare an empty array like below?
- Naming functions in general seems harder compared to the sentence like structure Obj-C allowed. Do most developers requires an external parameter name for the first argument in functions with more than one argument?

  ```
  func colorsAlongArray(colorArr:Array<UIColor>, steps:Int) -> Array<UIColor>
  {
      let arrCount = colorArr.count
      let stepIncrement = Double(arrCount)/Double(steps)
      var returnArr : Array<UIColor> = []

      for i in 0..<steps
      {
          let stepVal = stepIncrement*Double(i)
          let stepFactor = CGFloat(fmod(stepVal, 1.0))
          let stepIndex1 = Int(floor(stepVal/1.0))
          var stepIndex2 = Int(ceil(stepVal/1.0))

          if(stepIndex2 > arrCount-1)
              {stepIndex2 = arrCount-1}
          let color1 = colorArr[stepIndex1]
          let color2 = colorArr[stepIndex2]

          let color = colorByInterpolatingColors(color1, color2: color2, factor: stepFactor)
          returnArr += [color]
      }

      return returnArr
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the three issues you bring up.

- No implicit type conversion is a language convention, and is intended to make code safe.  This is by design, and is a bit verbose.  You can read about this in the [Numeric Type Conversion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID324) section of [The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) chapter in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).  You also do not get roll-over in arithmetic operations by default.
- Swift is strongly typed, so if you don't have an initial value to put into the array such that the [Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322) system can determine the type automatically (like `var returnArr = [UIColor.blackColor()]`), you'll have to specify the type in some manner.  But, you can use type inference and [Array Type Shorthand Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) to slightly shorten your array declaration (`var returnArr = [UIColor]()`).
- The naming guidelines for `Swift` are not the same as they are for `Objective-C`.  They are, in fact, more brief.  I suggest you check them out: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

You can create your `UIColor` array like this (either way):

```
var returnArr = [UIColor]()
var returnArr: [UIColor] = []
```

and I think you can do something like this in for loops:

```
for i in 0..<steps as! [Double] {

}
```